# The UV Map is correct, but the texture does not appear correctly

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I applied textures on the mesh in blender. The UV Map of the mesh is correct. However, when the textures are applied, the textures shows on the mesh as triangles. Please help
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe you forgot to shade smooth when you baked?

Comment: Actually its a 3d model that i exported from a game.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use the *Clear Custom Split Normals* option it will solve your problem, but I suggest you turn off the *Auto Smooth* option as well and clear the sharp edges (Select mesh edges > RMB > *Clear Sharp*).

[image]

Comment: Thank You For your assistance, but auto smooth was turned off by default and then i tried to clear sharp edge. It didnt work sadly.

Comment: I have attached my blend file and textures
https://www71.zippyshare.com/v/TnDoWoLD/file.html

Comment: I checked your blend file and I assume something went wrong with the exporting process, you should try it again. In my opinion, the problem is clearly with the UV map.

If you couldn't move forward with the exporting and couldn't get a better result you can create a new UV map for the mesh and snap the vertices onto the original UV map, but it'll take a lot of time to do this with all of your meshes, Unfortunately, I couldn't find a faster workflow to do this other than manually, I tried to transfer the UV but then I got back the original result.